# Methods of migrating mongoDB Database aside from mongodump and mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongoDB and I'm trying to find a method to migrate mongodb database.
I started a project with 2 other friends of mine where we create a mongoDB and upload its database into git. Our mongodb has around 200 collections and I think that just using `mongodump` and `mongorestore` everytime each of us commits changes to our project is not an effective method to update our database at git.

Is there any other methods to update changes and migrate data in mongoDB? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are trying to keep data in sync, collaboration via an online MongoDB deployment would be the most direct approach. I wouldn't recommend storing binary dumps in your `git` repo as that could add some significant bloat. If you need certain structural or shared data committed for development purposes, I would look into tools for schema migration. Schema migration scripts don't have to use the same language as your development stack, but typically there is more convenience and flexibility if you can share code/models for importing data. See the linked duplicate post for some examples.

Comment: @Stennie Thank you for the input. I still have one more question. At the moment me and my friends are using .NET Core for our project. I have search migration tools and found mongo-migrate which, if I believe right, need to run NodeJS as backend. Is there any migration tools that .NET can use directly? Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: The C# driver documentation has some information on [Handling Schema Changes](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/mapping/schema_changes/) in your code but I'm not aware of a specific C# framework or tool to suggest for managing schema migrations & loading data. Since asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow, perhaps you could ask on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or the [MongoDB User discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user).

Comment: One general approach would be something similar to [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io), an MIT licensed project which currently only supports SQL databases. If you can't find an existing tool you could perhaps add (or suggest adding) MongoDB support.